# Negation in Python

Tags: python, negation

I'm trying to create a directory if the path doesn't exist, but the ! (not) operator doesn't work. I'm not sure how to negate in Python... What's the correct way to do this?

```
if (!os.path.exists("/usr/share/sounds/blues")):
        proc = subprocess.Popen(["mkdir", "/usr/share/sounds/blues"])
        proc.wait()
```

Comment: By the way, why not use Python's `os.mkdir()`?

Comment: I wasn't aware of the os.mkdir() function, although I figured there was something like that.

Comment: It's better here to just `try: os.mkdir(path)` and handle the error. If you check first ('look before you leap') someone else can create or delete that folder after your check (but before you create it), and there could still be an error. The check doesn't guarantee anything at the time of creation. This idea is sometimes called ['easier to ask forgiveness than permission'](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-eafp).  

Even better (but even more specific to this problem), you can do `os.makedirs(path, exist_ok=True)` to create the path and ignore a `FileExistsError`.

Answer (score 291, accepted):

The negation operator in Python is `not`. Therefore just replace your `!` with `not`.

For your example, do this:

```
if not os.path.exists("/usr/share/sounds/blues") :
    proc = subprocess.Popen(["mkdir", "/usr/share/sounds/blues"])
    proc.wait()
```

---

For your specific example (as Neil said in the comments), you don't have to use the `subprocess` module, you can simply use [`os.mkdir()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.mkdir) to get the result you need, with added exception handling goodness.

Example:

```
blues_sounds_path = "/usr/share/sounds/blues"
if not os.path.exists(blues_sounds_path):
    try:
        os.mkdir(blues_sounds_path)
    except OSError:
        # Handle the case where the directory could not be created.
```

Answer (score 38):

Python prefers English keywords to punctuation. Use `not x`, i.e. `not os.path.exists(...)`. The same thing goes for `&&` and `||` which are `and` and `or` in Python.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#boolean-operations-and-or-not

Answer (score 15):

try instead:

```
if not os.path.exists(pathName):
    do this
```

Answer (score 3):

Combining the input from everyone else (use not, no parens, use `os.mkdir`) you'd get...

```
special_path_for_john = "/usr/share/sounds/blues"
if not os.path.exists(special_path_for_john):
    os.mkdir(special_path_for_john)
```

Comment: Your code (and the OP's) is an accident waiting to happen -- two instances of a longish literal string that presumably should be identical. And please don't retort that it's just an example -- it's a BAD example for newbies.