# Remove rows in python less than a certain value

Tags: python, pandas, row, multiple-columns

<sup>I feel like this question must have been answered by someone before, but I can't find an answer on stack overflow!</sup>

I have a dataframe `result` that looks like this and I want to remove all the values *less than or equal to* 10

```
>>> result
                       Name              Value      Date
189                   Sall                19.0  11/14/15
191                     Sam               10.0  11/14/15
192                 Richard               21.0  11/14/15
193                  Ingrid                4.0  11/14/15
```

This command works and removes all the values that are 10:

```
df2 = result[result['Value'] != 10]
```

But when I try to add the <= qualifier I get the error message `SyntaxError: invalid syntax`

```
df3 = result[result['Value'] ! <= 10]
```

I feel like there is probably a really simple solution.

Answer (score 66, accepted):

Instead of this

```
df3 = result[result['Value'] ! <= 10]
```

Use

```
df3 = result[~(result['Value'] <= 10)]
```

It will work. 
OR simply use

```
df3 = result[result['Value'] > 10]
```

Answer (score 14):

python doesn't use `!` to negate.  It uses `not`.  [See this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6117762/2336654)
In this particular example `!=` is a two character string that means `not equal`.  It is not the negation of `==`.

***option 1***
This should work unless you have `NaN`

```
result[result['Value'] > 10]
```

***option 2***
use the unary operator `~` to negate a boolean series

```
result[~(result['Value'] <= 10)]
```

Answer (score 9):

I have another suggestion, which could help

```
df3 = result.drop(result[result['Value'] < 10].index)
```

Answer (score 1):

There's also [`df.query()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.query.html):

```py
result.query('Value > 10')
```

```py
                       Name              Value      Date
189                   Sall                19.0  11/14/15
191                     Sam               10.0  11/14/15
192                 Richard               21.0  11/14/15
```